# Getting Large Amount of Emails From Outlook To Excel - Out Of Memory Error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to get all the emails that are in my Outlook Account with their "Body" element and list them in an Excel Sheet.

There are a lot of emails and because of that it gives an Out Of Memory Error.

I believe it occurs because of the "Body".

My code is below, I would appreciate if you can tell what I should do.

```
Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Operation")

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("email_Receipt_Date").Value Then
        Range("email_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("email_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("email_sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Sender
        Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
        Range("email_CC").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.CC
        Range("email_To").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.To
        Range("email_ID").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ConversationID

        i = i + 1
    End If
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing



End Sub
```

Comment: Your theory about the Text body (.Body) sounds reasonable since it will be the largest of the properties you save.  Have you tested this theory?  Comment out the statement that saves the text body; does this avoid the Out-Of-Memory error?  Change the statement to only save the first half of the text body; do you save twice as many emails before getting the Out-Of-Memory error?

Comment: Many modern emails have complex Html bodies (.HtmlBody) and the Text body, which is created from it, can be unintelligible.  Even if they are intelligible, they are difficult to read within a cell.  I used to archive emails like this, but I did not save the Text and Html bodies within the Excel workbook.  Instead I saved them as TXT and HTM files and created a hyperlink from the relevant row to these files.  This kept the workbook to a reasonable size and allowed me to see either body in its own window when required.

Comment: Hi Tony, yes you are right. I have tried with HTMLBody and I could get all my emails but the values in cells are not workable. What would be your solution to this? I dont understand why I get this problem with Body and not with HTMLBody @TonyDallimore

Comment: Very strange.  It would be a very unusual Html body to be much smaller than its text equivalent.  I suspect something else is at the root of your problem.  As I said I would not save either the Text nor the Html body in the workbook.  I would save them as separate files.  If you want I will expand what I mean as an answer.

Comment: @TonyDallimore I would appreciate as an answer

Comment: See if you can release memory with `Set OutlookMail = Nothing` just before `Next OutlookMail`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all items in a folder is not really a good and right idea:

```
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("email_Receipt_Date").Value Then
```

Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the Items class from the Outlook object model. They allow to apply a filter to the `Items` collection, returning a new collection containing all of the items from the original that match the filter.

The `Restrict` method is an alternative to using the `Find` method or `FindNext` method to iterate over specific items within a collection. The `Find` or `FindNext` methods are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The `Restrict` method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found.

```
Public Sub ContactDateCheck()  
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
    Dim myContacts As Outlook.Items  
    Dim myItem As Object  
    Dim DateStart As Date  
    Dim DateToCheck As String  
    Dim myRestrictItems As Outlook.Items  

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
    Set myContacts = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items  
    DateStart = #01/1/2020#  
    DateToCheck = "[LastModificationTime] >= """ & DateStart & """"  
    Set myRestrictItems = myContacts.Restrict(DateToCheck)  
    For Each myItem In myRestrictItems  
        If (myItem.Class = olContact) Then  
            MsgBox myItem.FullName & ": " & myItem.LastModificationTime  
        End If  
    Next  
End Sub
```

Comment: Will upvote if you would point OP to particular use case he is dealing with. MailItem rather than ContactItem, [ReceivedTime] rather than [LastModification] etc

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for the heads up but im a bit confused here. What I want to do is basically listing all my emails with their information (sender, date, subject etc.) Im not sure what to restrict here. What I want to do is probably easy and I get results with the code I have written but after 2100th line, it gives me the memory error. Is there anyway to fix it? I have tried HTMLBody and it worked but the contents in the HTMLBody cells is not workable with all the tags.

Comment: @Mert, you want to Restrict the Mailitems brought back to the Items instance. Restrict by ReceivedTime so that there are only those dated after `Range("email_Receipt_Date").Value`. Then you will have a lot less to iterate through to fill out your spreadsheeet.

Comment: @MacroMarc we don't provide ready-made solutions there. The sample code is for illustration purposes only how things are working together.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I suppose the key point is that iterating over the entire items of a folder is the issue, and OP can look into the Restrict method. Upvoted

Comment: @MacroMarc correct. Instead of iterating over all items, the OP needs to use `Restrict` or `Find`/`FindNext` methods.

Comment: @MacroMarc email_Receipt_Date is on 01-01-2020 but I am already getting emails starting from 12-02-2020, so, for the folder that I am working on, it is not really useful. Thats why the Restriction does not change the outcome. It works with HTMLBody but weirdly does not work with Body.

Comment: I have never seen your code with the `Restrict` method to say it is not really useful.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev your response is updated with Restrict method. It still gives an error. Actually it gives the error earlier than the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim myFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Operation")

Dim filterDateStr As String
'format your date string to an acceptable one for the Restrict method
filterDateStr = Format(Range("email_Receipt_Date").Value, "ddddd h:nn AMPM")
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
'Now return an Items instance that has restricted contents and set to a variable
Set myItems = myFolder.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" & filterDateStr & "'")

Dim i As Long: i = 1
'Loop through the restricted Items!
For Each OutlookMail In myItems
    If OutlookMail.Class = olMail Then  'check each item in the Items - is it an email Object?
        Range("email_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("email_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("email_sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Sender
        Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
        Range("email_CC").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.CC
        Range("email_To").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.To
        Range("email_ID").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ConversationID
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next OutlookMail

Set myFolder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Incidentally, you should qualify ranges to worksheets to avoid any accidental error if there is ever another active sheet.

Comment: It gave the same Out of Memory Error again after 692nd row. I also tried in a new file but gave the same error. Can there be any other problem that you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

As requested, a brief description of my system.  If this is not enough detail, please ask questions and I will update.

This is a description of a system I designed and built for myself perhaps 15 years ago.  It was probably my first Outlook macro.  My employer’s technical department gave us a limited allocation of disc space for our Outlook stores.  Most project communications were via email and on the longer projects we ran out of space before the project ended.  Most people printed their emails and deleted them, but I wanted electronic access until the end of the project.

My solution was like yours.  I had a routine which ran down all my folders and output details of every email to an Excel workbook.  The big differences, as I understand it were:

- The routine maintained the workbook.  For each email, it checked to see if the email had been archived before.  If it had not been archived before, it was archived.  If it had been archived before and `LastModificationTime` was unchanged, nothing was done.  If it had been archived before and `LastModificationTime` had changed, the previous record was marked for deletion and a new archive was created.  The routine sorted emails by date so only emails sent or received since the last archive needed examining.  I ran this routine everyday and it did not take long.
- I saved the text and Html bodies as files.  I also saved all attachments.  The row for the email containing hyperlinks using the `HYPERLINK` function.  (This was Outlook 2003; there are more powerful techniques today although `HYPERLINK` did everything I needed.)  All these files were saved in a dedicated folder named “Emails”.  Within this folder, I had a folder per year and within them a folder per month.  This limited the number of files per folder.  Files were named 000001.xxx, 000002.yyy and so on.  I maintained an index of the next available number for each month in a worksheet.
- I saved many more properties than you list in your macro.  Basically, I saved every property in which I was interested.  My idea was to allow me to “restore” an email if I needed it within my Outlook store again, but I never needed or coded this facility.

With the workbook as an index, I had complete access to every email I had ever received or sent even if they been deleted from my Outlook store.  I could sort emails by any property making it easy to find any that I wanted.  I could click on the hyperlinks to view either body and or any attachment.  Quite a few of my colleagues asked for their own copy or my macro when they saw how useful it was.  I also had my own archive of all my emails; I never really trusted out technical department's archives.

Hope this helps.  As I said at the beginning, ask for more detail if it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks fpr the insights. I'm trying to archive email, and running into memory problems. I like the idea of saving Text Body and HTML body to separate files and hyperlinking from the spreadsheet.  My VBA script runs out of memory on `excWks.Cells(intRow, 7) = olkMsg.HTMLBody`.  Could you post a code snippet on how to write to files and put links in the spreadsheet?  (I don't normally use VBA)

Answer (score 0):

You can release memory with `Set outlookMail = Nothing` in an indexed For loop.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outlookFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim outlookMail As Outlook.MailItem

Dim i As Long

Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set outlookFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Operation")

i = 1

Dim outlookFolderItems As Outlook.items
Dim outlookFolderItemsCount As Long

Set outlookFolderItems = outlookFolder.items
outlookFolderItemsCount = outlookFolderItems.Count
Debug.Print "outlookFolderItemsCount: " & outlookFolderItemsCount

' For testing without an Excel workbook
Dim email_Receipt_Date As Date
'email_Receipt_Date = Range("email_Receipt_Date").Value
email_Receipt_Date = Now - 50
Debug.Print "email_Receipt_Date: " & email_Receipt_Date

'The date range is "one-sided" no need to bring in Restrict
'  unless you are determined to do so
' Sort True = newest to oldest
outlookFolderItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

Dim j As Long
For j = 1 To outlookFolderItemsCount
    Debug.Print outlookFolderItems(j).ReceivedTime, outlookFolderItems(j).subject
Next j

'You cannot release memory in a For Each
'For Each OutlookMail In Folder.items

For j = 1 To outlookFolderItemsCount

    If TypeName(outlookFolderItems(i)) = "MailItem" Then
    
        Set outlookMail = outlookFolderItems(i)
        
        Debug.Print " i: " & i
        Debug.Print "outlookMail.ReceivedTime: " & outlookMail.ReceivedTime
        
        'If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("email_Receipt_Date").Value Then
        If outlookMail.ReceivedTime >= email_Receipt_Date Then
            
            Debug.Print " OutlookMail.subject.......: " & outlookMail.subject
            'Range("email_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.subject
            
            Debug.Print " OutlookMail.ReceivedTime..: " & outlookMail.ReceivedTime
            'Range("email_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
            
            Debug.Print " OutlookMail.Sender........: " & outlookMail.Sender
            'Range("email_sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Sender
            
            Debug.Print " OutlookMail.Body..........: " & outlookMail.Body
            'Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
            
            Debug.Print " OutlookMail.CC............: " & outlookMail.CC
            'Range("email_CC").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.CC
            
            Debug.Print " OutlookMail.To............: " & outlookMail.To
            'Range("email_To").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.To
            
            Debug.Print " OutlookMail.ConversationID: " & outlookMail.ConversationID
            'Range("email_ID").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ConversationID
            
            i = i + 1
            
        Else
            ' Exit when date not in single-sided range
            Debug.Print outlookMail.ReceivedTime & " is outside of single-sided range."
            Exit For
        
        End If
        
    End If
    
    Set outlookMail = Nothing   ' <--- Release in an indexed For loop
    
Next

Debug.Print "Done."

End Sub
```